# selectbox, a alert box shouldn't fire until a it hit the exact item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code.

**HTML**

```
<select id='item'>
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#item').click(function(){
        var type = $(this).val();
        if (type == "item1")
        {
            alert ('item1');
        }
        else if (type == "item2")
        {
            alert ('item2');
        }
        else if (type == "item3")
        {
            alert ('item3');
        }
    });
});
```

But whenever I hit the select box, it fires the alert box and it is kinda nasty. An alertbox should be fired when a user actually click the selective item. When a user hit the the item1 menu then it should only fire the alertbox of the item1.

Comment: change `$('#item').click` to `$('#item').on('change', function(){`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, why not answer the question instead of comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `change` api man: http://jsfiddle.net/eqHCN/

that will suffice the need. http://api.jquery.com/change/

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#item').change(function(){
        var type = $(this).val();
        if (type == "item1")
        {
            alert ('item1');
        }
        else if (type == "item2")
        {
            alert ('item2');
        }
        else if (type == "item3")
        {
            alert ('item3');
        }
    });
});​
```